# popToViewController is not working but popViewController does

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist.'
```

When using this code

```
self?.navigationController?.popToViewController(vc2, animated: true)
```

But when I try to pop simply its working

```
self?.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

I am pushing this viewController like

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(vc2, animated: true)
```

I am not sure, pushing a view means that when I try to do `popToViewController`. It has a view on top of it. Please help

Comment: Might be both the objects are not same at the time of push and pop. Can you please show the code from where you are pushing and from where you pop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:-

```
for obj in (self.navigationController?.viewControllers)! {
    if obj is TestViewController {
        let vc2: TestViewController =  obj as! TestViewController
        vc2.data = data
        self.navigationController?.popToViewController(vc2, animated: true)
        break
    }
}
```

Make sure your view controller is added on navigationcontroller stack.

Comment: Thnx for quick answer. One question, I am trying to pass data, But unable to do so with your code.ex - Code I am trying is obj.data = data.

Comment: cast your controller with obj and pass data.

Comment: Can you show me how  to do it
As I using let vc2 = self?.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TestViewController") as! TestViewController

and then using vc2,data = data

Comment: Please upvote my question, so more people get a chance to check your answer